# How to Distribute Points in a Poisson Distribution in a Circle

Tags: statistics, poisson-distribution

I have a circular area, and I need to distribute a certain number of points in this circle in a Poisson Distribution.

Functionally, how would I be able to distribute the points in a Poisson distribution? If I were to just place the points as 'randomly' as possible, would that be good enough?

Comment: A Poisson distribution is usually regarded as a function $\mathbb{Z}_{\geq 0} \to [0, 1]$; what do you mean "distribute points in a Poisson distribution"? This is especially difficult to interpret as a circle, unlike $\mathbb{Z}_{\geq 0}$, has no preferred point.

Comment: Do you mean a [Poisson-disk distribution](http://www.jasondavies.com/poisson-disc/)?

Comment: A bit ambiguous - distributed from what? The center of the disk? The edge? For the former, you could just generate pairs of randoms, one a uniform for angle, the other Poisson for distance.